# JS, jQuery not working when I refresh part of page with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have some JS files included in my page that are simple for displaying blocks on click ant etc..

On another part of page, I have a button. When I click it an ajax call is made that returns some values that I display on the page. To display it, I'm reloading part of page like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {product: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').data('id'),quantity: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val()},
        success: function (data) {
          if(data.success == false){
           alert('error')
          }else{
            $('.test').load(" .test");
            $('.sidebar').load(" .sidebar");
            $('.top').load(" .top");
           }
        }
    });
});
```

This reloads part of page, displays values and etc..

However, after the ajax call is made, the JS stops working. When I click my buttons, nothing happens. No errors or anything.

I think it has to do with the ajax when I refresh part of twig and it messes up the previously loaded JS files. But what can I do in that situation? Somehow refresh the loaded JS files? How?

Comment: any event is not working for that specific area, which is return by ajax right?

Comment: You should have an init() function to reset all the js events handlers. And call the function after each ajax() success response. So: `init() -> ajaxCall() -> init();` Because your dom is being changed after each ajax request.

Comment: jquery.load expects a url and you are giving class selector. This wont work, look for console, there might be some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said @Nacho M, you need to reinit listener from the loaded element, so you hsould have something like this :

```
function init() {
    $(document).on('click', '.yourclass', function (e) {
     //your content
    }

     // add every button who needs to be reloaded.
}
```

Init them on loading page first :

```
$("document").ready(function() {
init();
})
```

And on success of Ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'add',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {product: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').data('id'),quantity: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val()},
    success: function (data) {
      if(data.success == false){
       alert('error')
      }else{
        $('.test').load(" .test");
        $('.sidebar').load(" .sidebar");
        $('.top').load(" .top");
        init();
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to attach event listener on button starting from the container which doesn't get reloaded by Ajax request, like this:

```
//#mainCont is a container that doesn't get reloaded by Ajax

$("#mainCont").on("click", ".yourBtn", function(){
        //do something
});
```